# When is a $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell}$-local system the inverse image of a $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell}$-local system?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, etale-cohomology

I am trying to learn character sheaf theory, and encounter the following question:

(*) Let $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of quasi-projective smooth varieties over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q$, and suppose $\mathcal{L}$ is a rank $1$ lisse $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell}$-sheaf on $X$. My question is, usually under what condition on $f$, one can conclude the existence of a rank $1$ lisse $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell}$-sheaf $\mathcal{L}'$ on $Y$ such that $\mathcal{L}\cong f^*\mathcal{L}'$?

---

The two particular situations in my mind are:

(1) $f$ is a principal fibration by a torus. This is the case happened e.g. in Lusztig's paper Character Sheaves I - 2.4.

(2) $f$ is a principal fibration by a connected unipotent algebraic group. This is the case happened e.g. in Lusztig's new paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.05015v3.pdf - 4.2.

So I guess this might be true for any principal fibration by a connected affine algebraic group, or more generally true for a surjective morphism with isomorphic connected fibers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question as I find a general result covering the case in my mind:

This is true when $f$ is a locally trivial principal fibration by a connected algebraic group and the local system on $X$ is equivariant with respect to this group; it can be deduced as a special case of 1.9.3 in Lusztig's Character Sheaves I.